# Why doesn't wp-env know that my project is a WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm struggling to understand what wp-env expects from me in order to start theme development. My understanding is that I can just make the root of my project a WordPress theme and `wp-env start` would catch it up and understand that it's a theme.

I even tried to copy an existing theme and run `wp-env start` on it, but I always end up with this warning:

```bash
Warning: could not find a .wp-env.json configuration file and could
not determine if '/Users/me/www/my-theme' is a WordPress
installation, a plugin, or a theme.
```

What am I doing wrong? It's doesn't seem to be well documented.